# Nested Virtualization in aws bare Metal c5 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have a use case that I want to install windows 10 on an aws instance. Then on top of it, I want to install VMware workstation. In that VMware workstation, i want to install multiple VMs e.g kali, redhat, etc. Earlier this week, i had a simple aws instance( with server 2016) and it didn't allowed me to install VMs on vmware workstation inside server2016. It said that hypervisor and VMware can't stand simultanously. While looking for the resolution, I found exact same issue like mine:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=293113

And it said some thing like this:

Nested virtualization is not supported on AWS instances unless you are using AWS bare metal instances. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances-with-direct-access-to-hardware/

Now please clearly tell me that "if i get c5.xlarge bare metal instance of aws, then can I install my use case as i described in my first paragraph?" Please help. I couldn't find exact answer anywhere else!
Thank you in advance...

Comment: I don't understand this want. AWS EC2 is an unlimited pool of VMs at the click of a button. Why would you want to manage your own on AWS??

Comment: Also of note, a c5.metal instance is $2978/mo. You can run 24 c5.xlarge large instances for the same price.

Comment: I want to setup labs for students of my cybersecurity course. So i will provide each student a windows machine having VMware and some other VMs inside of it.

Comment: Please give me clear and straight forward answer of my question. I'm really tired of getting ambiguous answers on different forums. Please don't mind. I appreciate your response @jordanm. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a `c5.xlarge bare metal instance`.

Instances run on a physical 'host' in the AWS data center. Each host supports one 'family' of instances, such as `C5`. This is because each family has a specific type of processor and a particular ratio between CPU and RAM.

A C5 host has 96 vCPUs and 192 GB of RAM. This can be divided into different 'instance types' within the family, such as:

- `c5.large` with 2 vCPUs and 4 GB RAM
- `c5.xlarge` with twice as much (4, 8)
- `c5.12xlarge` with 12 times as much as a `c5.xlarge`
- All the way up to `c5.24xlarge` that has all 96 vCPUs and 192 GB of RAM

The instance type you choose basically gives you a 'slice' of the host.

If you wish to go **bare metal**, then you get the **entire host** with 96 vCPUs and 192 GB of RAM. When selecting bare metal, you get the whole host computer and it is big!

This is why you cannot get a `c5.xlarge` as a bare metal instance.

So, your choices are:

- Get a `c5.metal` instance, install VMWare and create smaller virtual computers, *or*
- Use [VMware Cloud on AWS](https://cloud.vmware.com/vmc-aws) where VMware runs the system for you and you can get smaller virtual computers, *or*
- Give your students Amazon EC2 instances (which would be the simplest option!), *or*
- Run your own hardware

Comment: Thank you soooo much for this detailed answer!!!. To add in my query, when it comes to ethical hacking, VMware workstation(or virtualbox etc) is a must!. If i follow the third option you gave me, wouldn't provide me the facility of VMware workstation inside. And the second option is quite complex for students to follow (as they also need to know things get setup). Any other suggestion e.g if I look for some other cloud services, etc.  Big thanks to this awesome community! I was not expecting such fast answers! Please help me further as well.

Comment: I'm not a VMware person, so can I ask what you are missing by providing an EC2 instance? What does "VMware workstation" provide that you require?

Comment: I can install kali linux VM, some purpose built vulnerable VMs in the vm ware workstaation. so that the students can try hacking on these vulnerable vms.

Comment: Ah! Yes, you might have problems with that on AWS.

Comment: @MuhammadMuaaz I would use VirtualBox to create your image, export it as OVF, and use AWS VM Import to create an AMI from it. Run the AMI in EC2.

Answer (score 0):

I think azure cloud are supporting nested virtualization.